# Inconveniente con Botón para Insertar registros en Jsp -Java

Tags: java, jsp

Cordial saludo, espero se encuentren bien soy Martín Hernández desde Colombia, agradezco por favor su colaboración para arreglar 2 inconvenientes que se me presentan al momento de insertar registros en un formulario.

El primer error concierne en que no puedo hacer el llamado a una función que tengo en Java dentro de una pagina Jsp, mas especificamente a la función que es la que valida cuando se ha presionado el botón con nombre btnGrabar (`name="btnGrabar"`),  y dentro del código la validacion que realizo, es la siguiente `if (request.getParameter("btnGrabar") != null) {`. Este es el código:

```
    <%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <%HttpSession sesion= request.getSession();%>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>JSP Page</title>
        
        </head>
        <body>
    
     <%  String txtNit,txtNombrecli;
                       
      txtNit=request.getParameter("txtNit");
      txtNombrecli=request.getParameter("txtNombrecli");  
     %>
           
           <h1><%=txtNit %></h1> 
           <h1><%=txtNombrecli %></h1> 
           Usuario: <%= sesion.getAttribute("nombre") %> |
           <a href="../index.jsp?cerrar=true">Cerrar Sesion</a>
            <h2 align="center">Registro de Proyectos</h2>
            <form action="">
                <table border="1" width="250" align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Id_proyecto</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="txtIdproy"></td> 
                    </tr> 
                    <tr>
                        <td>Nombre_proyecto</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="txtNombreproyecto"></td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Descripcion_general</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="txtDescrgral"></td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Proyciermeg</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="txtProyciermeg"></td> 
                    </tr> 
                    <tr>
                      <th colspan="2">
                      <input type="submit" name="btnGrabar" value="Grabar_Cliente">       
                   </tr> 
                </table>
    
      <%
                if (request.getParameter("btnGrabar") != null) {
                   String Nombreproyecto = request.getParameter("txtNombreproyecto");
                    String Descrgral = request.getParameter("txtDescrgral");
                    String Proycierneg = request.getParameter("txtProyciermeg");
                    String Nit = request.getParameter("txtNit");
                   
    
                    Connection cnx = null;
                    ResultSet rs = null;
                    Statement sta = null;
                    try {
                        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                        cnx = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/norgas?user=root&password=");
                        sta = cnx.createStatement();
    
                        sta.executeUpdate("insert into proyecto values ('" + Nombreproyecto + "','" + Descrgral + "','" + Proycierneg + "','" + Nit + "')");
                        request.getRequestDispatcher("ListadoClientes.jsp").forward(request, response);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        out.print(e + "");
                    }
                }
            %>
     <a href="ListadoProyecto.jsp" ><p style="text-align:center">Volver a Listado de proyectos</p></a>
          </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

la descripción de los inconvenientes los explico mas a profundidad en el siguiente video, agradezco si por favor me pueden colaborar:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_YFzyAGq7I

Muchas gracias por la colaboración

Comment: Hola, Martín. La pregunta preferiblemente, debe ser autocontenida. Si te bajan el canal en un mes, borras el video, Oracle lo baja por copyright :P  la pregunta ya no se va a poder usar en el futuro. Explícanos lo que nos debas explicar EN la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu error está en que estas usando el **executeUpdate**, pues si mal no recuerdo es para actualizar, prueba con una estructura así:

```
try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    cnx = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/norgas?user=root&password=");
                    sta = cnx.createStatement();

                    sta.execute("insert into proyecto values ('" + Nombreproyecto + "','" + Descrgral + "','" + Proycierneg + "','" + Nit + "')");
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("ListadoClientes.jsp").forward(request, response);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    out.print(e + "");
                }
```

Puedes basarte en esto también:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haberte ayudado.
Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias Sr Jeyson, realice lo que usted me comenta pero me aparece este otro inconveniente, Agradezco por favor cualquier idea:  Cordial saludo, espero se encuentren bien, agradezco su colaboracion por fa or en el siguiente asunto: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=diiDk4wPn5k&feature=youtu.be     
Muchas gracias, que pena la molesta!.